# No @Inject or default constructor found error in Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, inject

My code is fairly simple and outogenerated by Eclipse.

```
public class BuchAnalysisPresenter extends
            Presenter<BuchAnalysisPresenter.MyView, BuchAnalysisPresenter.MyProxy>
            implements BuchAnalysisUiHandlers {
        interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<BuchAnalysisUiHandlers> {

            SimplePanel getMain();
        }

        @ContentSlot
        public static final Type<RevealContentHandler<?>> SLOT_BUCHNR = new Type<RevealContentHandler<?>>();

        @NameToken(NameTokens.buchnummer)
        @ProxyStandard
        interface MyProxy extends ProxyPlace<BuchAnalysisPresenter> {
        }

        @Inject
        VerlagServiceAsync verlagServiceAsync;

        @Inject
        BuchAnalysisPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy) {

            super(eventBus, view, proxy, HomePagePresenter.SLOT_SetGraphContent);
            getView().setUiHandlers(this);
        }
    }
```

But I get a compile error saying:

`Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for de.it2media.dps.statistics.client.application.buchnranalysis.BuchAnalysisPresenter$MyView`

As you can see in the code that there is in fact a constructor `BuchAnalysisPresenter`and the `@Inject`annotation with it.

I'm very new to `Spring` and don't know why this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I only had to call the `install()` method of `GinBinder` and initialize my module `BuchAnalysisModule` like so. No other changes necessary.

```
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    install(new BuchAnalysisModule());

    bindPresenter(ApplicationPresenter.class,
                ApplicationPresenter.MyView.class, ApplicationView.class,
                ApplicationPresenter.MyProxy.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a bean of type MyView in your context? If not, Spring will attempt to instantiate one, which won't work with an interface.

2 possible ways to fix this:

1. Define a bean of the proper type in the Spring context
2. Change the type of the constructor param:

   ```
   BuchAnalysisPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyViewImpl view, MyProxy proxy)
   ```

Comment: I don't have a Bean of that type defined. But there are other similar presenters in my project with the same autogenerated code and they all work fine.

Comment: So if I change the type of the parameter to ´MyViewImpl´, where would I define that type? As shown in the code, it extends ´View´class so doesn't matter which name I give, it doesn't work..

Comment: You need to use a class that implements this interface. In my example MyViewImpl implements MyView. If you don't have any possible implementation of the class, you could also simply remove the "view" constructor argument and simply initialise it using: `MyView view = new MyView() {public SimplePanel getMain() {/* do something */}};`

Comment: In my opinion this solution isn't very clean, I prefer to avoid anonymous classes and declare concrete classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

In My case the issue was that I was using wrong HashMap implementation in my `View` class like below:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

> The issue was with imported classes

I was importing correct Map interface but wrong HashMap class

The imports were like:

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gwt.dev.util.collect.HashMap;
```

I Replaced the HashMap by the following and it worked :)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
```